# DynamoDB - simple explanation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

## Question

Having gone through verbose AWS documentations, I need some help to clarify the basic keywords and concept of DynamoDB.

Kindly assist to confirm if these are correct.

### Hash key

The key which decides the partition of the item, so it is also called as the 'partition' key.

### Primary key

A hash key, or (hash-key, range-key) pair that can identify only 1 item in the table. A (hash-key, range-key) pair is also called 'composite' key.

If **the** primary key has only hash-key, "*hash-key*" and "*primary-key*" can be used interchangeably(but doing so can cause confusions).

### Local secondary index

In a simple term, "alternative range key" to be used with the hash-key of the primary key.

Besides the range key in the primary key (hash-key, range-key), we can have additional range keys that can be used with the hash-key of the primary key.

### Global secondary index

Alternative (hash-key, range-key) pairs for **Query**.

[KeyConditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html)

> For a query on a table, you can have conditions **only on the range key portion on the table/index primary key**.  The hash key condition must always be `equal`.

### Expression attribute name

Dozens of words cannot be used as its attribute name in DynamoDB table, such as status. It is a way to get around this restriction to be able to use such word by prefixing with '#'. Perhaps a design error of DyanmoDB.

### Key condition expression

SQL WHERE like part of **Query** which needs a hash-key of the primary key. It seems it identifies the one partition to get items, then additionally we can use a range-key to narrow down items.

[KeyConditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html)

> For a query on a table/index, you can have conditions **only on the table/index primary key attributes**. You must always provide the partition key name and value as an EQ condition. You can optionally provide a second condition, referring to the sort(aka range) key.

### Filter expression

SQL WHERE like part that can be used for both with **Query** and **Scan** but only with **non-key** attributes.

[Filter Expressions for Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression)

> A filter expression **cannot contain partition key or sort key** attributes. You need to specify those attributes in the key condition expression, not the filter expression.

If used in **Query** in addition to the key expression, the unmatched items are thrown away.

Comment: edited...you were pretty close, only `query()` makes use of the keys.  `Scan()` just reads the entire table/index.

Comment: "Filter Expression" - you are correct in terms of unmatch items are thrown away. Keep in mind, the READ - for all the records that were initially read before the filter was applied. so the queries can use up your read capacity fairly fast if you aren't careful. Other than that, you are spot on.